# How to go back to previous state of recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh

How to go back to previous state of recyclerview. I mean I have 5 items in recyclerview, after pull to refresh count is 10 items. Suppose I want to go back to previous state of recyclerview i.e 5 elements using back button, how do I handle it?